# Проверка на ввод только чисел

Tags: scanner

Написал программу, которая принимает два числа, а потом оперирует. Но если я ввожу букву, то выдаёт ошибку, как сделать так, чтобы если вводил не цифры, то заново выводило сообщение на ввод числа, а не выдавало ошибку? Спасибо.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyProject4 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        float i;
        float k;
        float s;
        String str = null;

        while (true) {

            Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Введите первое число");
            i = scn.nextFloat();
            System.out.println("Введите второе число");
            k = scn.nextFloat();
            System.out
                    .println("Введите: (+ сложить) (- вычесть) (* умножить) (/ делить)");
            str = scn.next();

            if (str.equals("+")) {
                s = i + k;
                if (s - (int) s == 0)
                    System.out.println((int) s);
                else
                    System.out.println(s);
            }

            if (str.equals("-")) {
                s = i - k;
                if (s - (int) s == 0)
                    System.out.println((int) s);
                else
                    System.out.println(s);
            }

            if (str.equals("*")) {
                s = i * k;
                if (s - (int) s == 0)
                    System.out.println((int) s);
                else
                    System.out.println(s);
            }

            if (str.equals("/")) {
                s = i / k;
                if (s - (int) s == 0) {
                    System.out.println((int) s);
                } else {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Введите q для выхода или любую другую для продолжение");
            str = scn.next();
            if (str.equals("q")) {
                System.out.println("Выход");
                return;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример взят из http://kostin.ws/java/java-input-stream.html - первая же ссылка в гугле по вопросу "java scanner описание"

```
import java.util.Scanner; // импортируем класс
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // создаём объект класса Scanner
        int i = 2;
        System.out.print("Введите целое число: ");
        if(sc.hasNextInt()) { // возвращает истинну если с потока ввода можно считать целое число
          i = sc.nextInt(); // считывает целое число с потока ввода и сохраняем в переменную
          System.out.println(i*2);
        } else {
          System.out.println("Вы ввели не целое число");
        }
    }
}
```